# Adding a fixed number of rows in datagridview in c# in the .cs design form

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a datagridview with 25 rows containing three columns and next option for going to next records of a local database,containing employee name id.employee and view profile button.but cant add a single row from the tool box..how is it possible to do in the design form?

Comment: Why do you want to that in the designer? You really want to just do that in the code: in `loadform` for example.

Answer (score 4):

1. Drag drop `DataGridView` control.
2. In `Form_Load` event write:

> datagridView1.RowCount = 25;